# Kafka Connect on CFK: Discrepancies between Connect Rest api and Connect CR by CFK

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I installed confluent using CFK (Confluent for Kubernetes) way of deployment, setup went fine, using the vanilla yaml file for the entire components (zookeeper, kafka, connect, ksql, control-center, schema-registry).

I tried to use `kind: Connector` to configure my sqlserver source connector, connector created succesfully.

The problem came when I tried to list the connector via the below curl request (after port-forwarding to the pod)
`curl localhost:8083/connectors | jq .`

I got nothing registered, however when I ran the below command:

`kubectl confluent connector list`

it shows that I have a registered connectors as below, I assume both are 2 faces for the same coin.

```
NAME                          STATUS  TASKS-READY  TASKS-FAILED  AGE
bq-sink-conn                            0             9h
mssql-source-conn                       0             9h
```

My question is, **why is this discrepancy?, or I am missing something**

also after a week of searching and looking on the internet, I can't find enough resources with example on how to use CFK and specifically Connectors CR.

Thanks,

Comment: Please clarify what is `localhost`? Did you `kubectl port-forward`? In other words, are you running Connect server outside of Kubernetes on your current computer (where there are no connectors)?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, yes, I mentioned that ran the curl on localhost after portforwading, and all kafka components are running on GKE cluster including kafka-connect

Comment: I've not used CFK, but the curl response should be the same as the operator output unless the operator resources are out-of-sync with the actual server. You'd need to run `kubectl logs` for the Connect operator pod(s) to find issues with it. Also, did you mean `kubectl -n confluent connector list`?

Comment: I think it could be a bug, I will give it another shot and if same happens will open a github issue, and no, for the command not `-n confluent`, there is a confluent plugin for kubectl that enable such a command in my question.